# Initializing a list of QColors in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

How can I initialize a static list of QColors. I'm using Qt 5.11.1

In my header file i have this:

```
QList<QColor> *colorList;
```

not sure if it's more appropriate for me to use this

```
QColor *colorList[15];
```

Then in what would i write in the CPP file... something like this?:

```
colorList = {
    QColor(220,0,0),
    QColor(250,140,0),
    QColor(255,255,0),
    QColor(145,210,80),
    QColor(0,180,20),
    ...
};
```

I'll be eventually looping through this list of colors using the color.

**Update**
I'm getting an error when looping through the colors. Which I'm using the colors to define the visual color of a QPushButton I subclassed.

Here are the import bits of the code.

**.h**

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <colorswatch.h>
#include <QColorDialog>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QList>

class ColorSwatchPicker : public ColorSwatch
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...

private:
    void init();
    ...
    QList<QColor> *colorList;
};
```

**.cpp**

```
void ColorSwatchPicker::createButtons()
{
    //! create color swatch menu
    QWidget *colorWidget = new QWidget(this);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(colorWidget);
    layout->setSpacing(4);
    layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

    // create color swatches
    colorList = new QList<QColor>({
            QColor(255,70,50),
            QColor(230,30,100),
            QColor(155,40,175),
            QColor(105,60,185),
            QColor(65,80,180),
            ...
        });

    // Create the pushbutton control
    foreach (const QColor &c, colorList) {
        auto *cs = new ColorSwatch(c, this);
        cs->setFixedSize(18,18);
    };
```

}

[image]

Comment: `QList<QColor> *colorList;` is a pointer to a list of colors.  `QColor *colorList[15];` is an array of pointers to colors.  Personally, I would use `const std::array<QColor, 15> = {{ ... }};`

Comment: In both cases why do you need the pointer?

Comment: What version of C++ are using? Do you have C++11? C++14? C++17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define an [alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) (optional)

   ```
   using ColorList = QList<QColor>;
   ```
2. Initialize the list

   ```
   auto *colorList = new ColorList({
       QColor(220,0,0),
       QColor(250,140,0),
       QColor(255,255,0),
       // ...
   });
   ```
3. Iterate over the colors in `colorList`

   ```
   foreach (const QColor &c, *colorList) {
       // do something with c
   }
   ```

   **Note (thanks to @drescherjm and @AlbertoMiola)**: Alternatively you can use a *ranged for* instead of `foreach`:

   ```
   for (const auto &c : *colorList) {
       // do something with c
   }
   ```

Comment: `foreach` these days I convert this to a ranged for in my code when I get a chance..

Comment: step 1? Where are you placing that? In the header file?

Comment: @drescherjm, I am just updating Qt. I am going to fix that in a moment.

Comment: @JokerMartini, yes, or after the includes in the implementation file (*.cpp).

Comment: Another option, more c++ modern style, would be: for( const auto& c : colorList)

Comment: @scopchanov I'm updating the question because I'm getting errors trying to use your recommended solution. I'm sure im doing something wrong

Comment: @JokerMartini, it is because the pointer. I have fixed that already.